# Dynamically Added Rows and Calculation Function Error After First Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm working a project, it is almost done but I got a problem to finish it. I tried a lot of things and searched on the web, but unfortunately I could not succeed it.

The problem is about dynamically added rows at the table. Auto-calculating script is just working on the first row of the table, at 2nd, 3rd, ... rows of the table it does not work.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3W48W/) for below the code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$("#AddLine").click(function () {
        //var row = "<tr><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><input type=text /></td><td><button>X</button></td></tr>";
        var row = "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" name=\"stokkodu[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" name=\"stokadi[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" id=\"miktar\" class=\"miktar\" name=\"miktar[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" name=\"birim[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" id=\"birimfiyat\" class=\"birimfiyat\" name=\"birimfiyat[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" readonly id=\"tutar\" class=\"tutar\" name=\"tutar[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"indirim\" name=\"indirim[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" readonly class=\"indirimtutar\" name=\"indirimtutari[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" class=\"kdv\" name=\"kdv[]\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;\" readonly class=\"satirtoplami\" name=\"satirtoplami[]\"></td><td><button>X</button></td></tr>";
        $("#table").append(row);
    });

$("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
   $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[id=miktar],input[id=birimfiyat],input[id=indirim],input[id=kdv], input[id=satirtoplami]').change(function(e)  {
        var total_mnozi = 0;
        //var $row = $(this).parent();
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); //this is the closest common root of the input elements
        var miktar = parseFloat( $row.find('input[id=miktar]').val() );
        var birimfiyat = parseFloat( $row.find('input[id=birimfiyat]').val() );
        var indirim = parseFloat( $row.find('input[id=indirim]').val() );
        var kdv = parseFloat( $row.find('input[id=kdv]').val() );


         //total_mnozi = ((dep + minpre + adjpre) * procombase * profcomper) || 0; //calculate traditionally; display zero until result is meaningful
          tutar = (miktar * birimfiyat) || 0;  // tutar hesaplama. miktar x birim fiyat = tutar 
          indirimtutar= (tutar * indirim / 100) || 0;  // indirim tutarı hesaplama input'a girilen %'ye göre hesaplar.
          satirtoplami= ((tutar - indirimtutar) * ((kdv / 100) + 1 )) || 0;
          $row.find('input[id=tutar]').val(tutar.toFixed(2));  // tutar'ın id="tutar"'a virgülden sonra 2 hane alacak şekilde yazdrılması.
          $row.find('input[id=indirimtutar]').val(indirimtutar.toFixed(2));
          $row.find('input[id=satirtoplami]').val(satirtoplami.toFixed(2));

    });
});

//]]>  

</script>
<input type="button" id="AddLine" value="add"/>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td scope="col">Stok Kodu</th>
            <td scope="col">Stok Adı</th>
            <td scope="col">Miktar</th>
            <td scope="col">Birim</th>
            <td scope="col">Birim Fiyat</th>
            <td scope="col">Tutar</th>
            <td scope="col">İndirim (%)</th>
            <td scope="col">İndirim Tutarı</th>
            <td scope="col">KDV (%)</th>
            <td scope="col">Satır Toplamı</th>
            <td scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" name="stokkodu[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" name="stokadi[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="miktar" class="miktar" name="miktar[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" name="birim[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="birimfiyat" class="birimfiyat" name="birimfiyat[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" readonly id="tutar" class="tutar" name="tutar[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="indirim" class="indirim" name="indirim[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" readonly id="indirimtutar" class="indirimtutar" name="indirimtutari[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" id="kdv" class="kdv" name="kdv[]"></td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100%;" readonly id="satirtoplami" class="satirtoplami" name="satirtoplami[]"></td>
            <td><button>X</button></td>
        </tr>
</table>​
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It would help if you more specifically described the problem and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with duplicate Ids.

You should not add two or more elements with the same `Id`. So, to solve the problem, your dynamically added elements should not have `id` attributes, then you use the `class` attribute to target the elements in each row.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/3W48W/2/ (incorporating @Barmar 's answer)

HTM

Comment: but if i add inputs manually, it works with the same id. also i tried this using class attribute but it does not work. can you send me an simple exlample which include calculation and add new row function?

Comment: Please see working sample (incorporating @Barmar 's answer): http://jsfiddle.net/3W48W/2/

Comment: So if I want to calculate the value of 'satır toplamı' at all rows. How can i do?
total += parseFloat(satirtoplami);
    $('input:total').html(total);
it does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

First, you're using the same IDs in each row that you add dynamically. IDs are required to be unique.

Second, the `.change()` binding only applies to elements that are in the DOM at the time the page is loaded. To handle elements added dynamically, you need to use `.on()` to bind to a permanent element and delegate to the dynamic elements, or bind the event handler to the new row's elements after you append it to the DOM.

Comment: how could i do? could you do it on a simple example for me?